# Mozilla don't want to accept negative margin value?

Tags: html, css

I'm developing responsive website via Joomla (Gantry template) and I'm using media queries to set margin values regarding the different resolutions. The problem here is that Chrome and Safari get the CSS declaration rather than Mozilla. How to avoid that?

The "maintop" sections consist of one header image and bottom there are other elements, I want to reduce the distance between the "main-top" section and "main-bottom" section into different resolutions.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="rt-mainbody-surround">
<div id="rt-maintop">
<div id="rt-container">
<div id="rt-grid-12 rt-alpha rt-omega"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="rt-container"></div>
<div id="rt-mainbottom"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
@media all and (max-width: 2660px) and (min-width: 1200px) {
#rt-maintop{margin-bottom: -7.5%;
background: url(../images/custom/bckg.png);
display:block;
width:100%; 
height:auto;}
}
@media all and (max-width: 1199px) and (min-width: 960px) {
#rt-maintop{margin-bottom: -8%;
background: url(../images/custom/bckg.png);
display:block;
width:100%; 
height:auto;}
}
@media all and (max-width: 959px) and (min-width: 768px) {
#rt-maintop{margin-bottom: -10%;
background: url(../images/custom/bckg.png);
display:block;
width:100%; 
height:auto;}
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), show us your research so far.

Comment: Here is the link of the site:
http://mediatecture.dev.diewerkbank.eu

Comment: Please don't like to the site @Nemez, sites can change or go offline very easily, please provide a working code sample that demonstrates the problem you're having.